# How to create UICollectionView like zig-zag

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uicollectionview

I have attached screen show which is i want. I am tried bellow code but not getting as showing result

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ZigZagCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! ZigZagCollectionCell
        
        cell.setUpCell()
        
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell.viewBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
            cell.viewBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

And I want this type of collection view. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Two options 1. Subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` 2. Use `compositional flow layout` you will find plenty of tutorial for both

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reference link it will help me?

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya please have look to link https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Answer (score 0):

as @Sandeep Bhandari said, subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

then, you give every item its own frame.

1, Firstly, in `override public func prepare()`

calculate every item's frame,

& use `private var cache = [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()` to store,

> this is the key step for you, to set up every item's frame.

2, secondly, provide frame data for each item.

```
override public func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
       return cache[indexPath]
}
```

3, thirdly, provide frame data for all, including item / decoration view / supplemental view

```
override public func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    guard let _ = collectionView else { return nil }
    
    visibleLayoutAttributes.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
   
      for (_, attributes) in cache {
        attributes.transform = .identity
        if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
            visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
      }
    
    return visibleLayoutAttributes
  }
```

Here is relevant example [github repo](https://github.com/BoxDengJZ/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout)